# Cannot align to center favButton with cards inside a column

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a view that has two cards , one below the other, my requirement is to place a fab button in the middle of these two cards like this image below

[image]

I tried doing it with offsets and a column, I also tried adding a box, but seems like is not working as I expect

```
@Preview
@Composable
private fun CardsAndFabPreview() {
    Column(horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
        ArbitrageCard(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(vertical = 8.dp, horizontal = 16.dp).offset(y = 30.dp),
            isBuyAt = true,
            buyAt = "Binance",
            sellAt = "Kucoin",
            buyPrice = "0.32",
            sellPrice = "0.66",
            pair = "BTC/USDT"
        )
        FloatingActionButton(
            onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
            Icon(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_baseline_arrow_upward_24),
                contentDescription = "",
                tint = Color.White
            )
        }
        ArbitrageCard(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(vertical = 8.dp, horizontal = 16.dp).offset(y = -30.dp),
            isBuyAt = false,
            buyAt = "Binance",
            sellAt = "Kucoin",
            buyPrice = "0.32",
            sellPrice = "0.66",
            pair = "BTC/USDT"
        )
    }
}
```

This is my output, the problem is that if I wrap this fab with a box, it wont draw above my two cards, and I also need to add these offsets in the y axis to make them look like this which I want to know if there is a way of removing these offsets and do it more cleaner

[image]